# Text wrap in ReportLab Table causes row overlap

Tags: python, pypdf, reportlab

I am trying to output a table to an existing pdf using ReportLab. I added text wrapping to columns 2, 5 and 6 using Paragraph() and a styles["Normal"] with "LTR" wordWrap. But now my heights look all weird and the text overlaps, I can't figure out a way to make it so that the cell heights are dynamic according to the wrapped text.
[image]

I have tried to change the style to styles["BodyText"] changed the table style "VALIGN" property but can't seem to make it work, am I missing something?

```
import locale
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now
import pandas as pd

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from core.models import CondoSale
from core.external_utils import gen_gmaps_img, gen_lat_lon

from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader
import io
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle, Paragraph
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("-m", "--market", type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        market_name = options.get("market", None)
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")

        packet = io.BytesIO()

        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Inter-Bold", "Inter-Black.ttf"))
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Inter", "Inter[slnt,wght].ttf"))
        can = canvas.Canvas(packet, bottomup=0)
        sales = self.get_sales(market_name)

        can.setFont("Inter-Bold", 22)
        can.drawString(180, 50, "Recent Condo Sales $1M+")
        
        # allow text warpping
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styleN = styles["Normal"]
        styleN.wordWrap = "LTR"

        can.setFont("Inter", 18)

        can.setFillColor(colors.HexColor("#68C5DB"))
        can.drawString(180, 70, "Brickell, Miami | September 2023")
        data = []
        for sale in sales:
            if len(data) ==10:
                break
            buyers = sale.concat_buyers
            sellers = sale.concat_sellers
            if len(buyers) > 25:
                buyers = f"{buyers[:22]}..."
                sellers = f"{sellers[:22]}..."
           data.append([str(sale.closing_date), Paragraph(sale.condo_unit.building.alt_name, styleN), sale.condo_unit.unit_no,f"{sale.condo_unit.sf:n}", "${0}".format(locale.format("%d", sale.sale_price, True)), Paragraph(sellers, styleN), Paragraph(buyers, styleN)])
        data.append(["Closing Date", "Building", "Unit:", "SF", "Sale Price", "Sellers", "Buyers"])
        t=Table(data, colWidths=[65, 120, 45, 45, 70,110, 110], style=[('LINEABOVE',(0,0),(6,-1),0.1,colors.gray), ("VALIGN", (0, 0), (-1, -1), "MIDDLE")])


        width, height = letter
        t.wrapOn(can, width, height)
        t.drawOn(can, 28, 300)

        can.save()

        #move to the beginning of the StringIO buffer
        packet.seek(0)

        # create a new PDF with Reportlab
        new_pdf = PdfReader(packet)
        # read your existing PDF
        existing_pdf = PdfReader(open("sample_report.pdf", "rb"))
        output = PdfWriter()
        # add the "watermark" (which is the new pdf) on the existing page
        page = existing_pdf.pages[0]
        page.merge_page(new_pdf.pages[0])
        output.add_page(page)
        # finally, write "output" to a real file
        output_stream = open("destination.pdf", "wb")
        output.write(output_stream)
        output_stream.close()
```